# Is there any difference between those?

Tags: haskell

I just started to learn Haskell and while reading the "Learn You a Haskell" book I got a question. Is there any difference between those two ways of doing essentially the same thing:

```
qtz 1 = [1]
qtz x
    | even x = x : qtz (x `div` 2)
    | odd  x = x : qtz (x * 3 + 1)

-- this
length (filter (>15) (map length (map qtz [1..100])))
-- and this
length (filter (\ xs -> length xs > 15) (map qtz [1..100]))
```

Comment: Here it will not make much difference, the result of the `filter (>15) (map length (map qtz [1..100]))` expression is different, since that will be a list of lengths, whereas for `filter (\ xs -> length xs > 15) (map qtz [1..100])` it is a list of lists (the result of the `qtz` items) with length larger than `15`. But since you call `length` on that you "throw away" the elements of the list.

Comment: please edit your question title its not indicating proper title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, both will yield the same answer, there is a difference in the subexpressions `filter (>15) (map length (map qtz [1..100]))` and `filter (\ xs -> length xs > 15) (map qtz [1..100])` however. In the former, you create a list of lengths, and then filter out the elements that are less than or equal to `15`, so this gives us:

```
Prelude> filter (>15) (map length (map qtz [1..100]))
[17,20,18,18,21,21,16,16,24,112,19,19,19,107,27,22,22,22,35,110,30,17,17,17,105,25,25,25,113,113,20,33,20,33,20,20,108,108,28,28,28,103,23,116,23,23,23,36,36,23,111,111,31,31,18,31,18,93,18,18,106,106,119,26,26,26]
```

In the latter we make a list of sequences, and we filter out the sequences that have less than or equal to 15 elements:

```
Prelude> filter (\ xs -> length xs > 15) (map qtz [1..100])
[[7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1],[9,28,14,7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1],[14,7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1],…]
```

But that does not matter, since you call `length` on these lists, and `length` is not interested in the individual elements, but only in the number of elements, so it basically "throws away" the elements in the list.

Using `length` to determine if a list has more than a given number of elements is often not that efficient. If the list contains thousands of elements, it will first determine the length, and then compare that to `15`. If the list has infinite length, it will even get stuck in an infinte loop. Some utility libraries offer a function like [**`lengthAtLeast :: Int -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.15/docs/Data-List-HT.html#v:lengthAtLeast), which will stop from the moment the required length is reached, or the list is exhausted.

You can thus rewrite the function to:

```
import Data.List.HT(lengthAtLeast)

(length . filter (lengthAtLeast 16) . map qtz) [1..100]
```